# Download File from MegaUP C#

Tags: c#, html, download, html-agility-pack, megaupload

I want to download a file from this site: https://megaup.net in C#

I tried to use HtmlAgilityPack to search for something in the webpages html.
You can find a function that uses 4 parameters

```
DeObfuscate_String_and_Create_Form_With_Mhoa_URL('v7tREbriBy55DAqebUXHcmaKJ98L5VaLxil0CKBQb/ot53hZhRrqTNyELj6+8ctJ5bcPLq2aAUUwiVMDMOXPbrxh7dYv1PPxGBvvivZCX5dL3ElEmN7Q0LMlUmwdKEEt8kU0sShl5U0ggdtl', 'C3J=8P1XjsUpV+xbYL6Pu7P33cboO+Cqb883rLQJs7dXa38TEf7zjTLMYW+tROsNXs6ZSYM8g8=', 'Tets.txt', '0.00 KB');}
```

Then you get the function

```
function DeObfuscate_String_and_Create_Form_With_Mhoa_URL(d1, d2, FileName, FileSize) {

var _0x3e69ce=_0x4d09;(function(_0x49d3cb,_0x3b38c8){var _0x118532=_0x4d09,_0x38c239=_0x49d3cb();while(!![]){try{var _0x2c890e=parseInt(_0x118532(0x1d1))/0x1*(-parseInt(_0x118532(0x1d2))/0x2)+parseInt(_0x118532(0x1cb))/0x3+parseInt(_0x118532(0x1c2))/0x4*(parseInt(_0x118532(0x1c3))/0x5)+-parseInt(_0x118532(0x1d4))/0x6+-parseInt(_0x118532(0x1d3))/0x7*(parseInt(_0x118532(0x1c8))/0x8)+-parseInt(_0x118532(0x1c5))/0x9*(parseInt(_0x118532(0x1ca))/0xa)+-parseInt(_0x118532(0x1d0))/0xb*(-parseInt(_0x118532(0x1be))/0xc);if(_0x2c890e===_0x3b38c8)break;else _0x38c239['push'](_0x38c239['shift']());}catch(_0x20b931){_0x38c239['push'](_0x38c239['shift']());}}}(_0x18cf,0xd2845));function _0x4d09(_0x18b8d8,_0x4b0fdf){var _0x18cfab=_0x18cf();return _0x4d09=function(_0x4d09b3,_0x4279e8){_0x4d09b3=_0x4d09b3-0x1b7;var _0x11388c=_0x18cfab[_0x4d09b3];return _0x11388c;},_0x4d09(_0x18b8d8,_0x4b0fdf);}var url_da_encrypt='';for(i=d1['length']/0x4-0x1;i>=0x0;i--){url_da_encrypt+=d1[i];}for(i=d1['length']/0x4*0x3-0x1;i>=d1['length']/0x4*0x2;i--){url_da_encrypt+=d1[i];}for(i=(d2[_0x3e69ce(0x1bc)]-0x3)/0x2+0x2;i>=0x3;i--){url_da_encrypt+=d2[i];}function _0x18cf(){var _0x22423f=['.metaRedirectWrapperBottomAds','6960hAemGr','value','.metaRedirectWrapperBottomAds\x20>\x20div\x20>\x20a\x20>\x20img','round','1535748kdMLiB','5vYRxkJ','none','76869kBinpb','height','innerHeight','40RyXpkG','idfilesize','750fSzPDS','1120860mSloFI','#M9319823','innerWidth','idfilename','getElementById','35893DqJkeH','5IpMqTD','63438AdwvRm','1021846BZXjUq','1552560wquncb','opacity','.download-timer','css','clientWidth','.imgAds','idurl','<img\x20src=\x27https://megaup.net/themes/flow/frontend_assets/images/adblock/primary.png\x27>','setAttribute','clientHeight','<form\x20action=\x27https://download.megaup.net/\x27\x20method=\x27get\x27\x20style=\x27text-align:\x20center;\x27><input\x20id=\x27idurl\x27\x20type=\x27hidden\x27\x20name=\x27idurl\x27><input\x20id=\x27idfilename\x27\x20type=\x27hidden\x27\x20name=\x27idfilename\x27><input\x20id=\x27idfilesize\x27\x20type=\x27hidden\x27\x20name=\x27idfilesize\x27><input\x20id=\x27btnsubmit\x27\x20type=\x27submit\x27\x20class=\x27btn\x20btn-default\x27\x20value=\x27Create\x20Download\x20Link\x27></form>','body','html','length'];_0x18cf=function(){return _0x22423f;};return _0x18cf();}var width_trinh_duyet=window[_0x3e69ce(0x1cd)]||document['documentElement'][_0x3e69ce(0x1d8)]||document[_0x3e69ce(0x1ba)][_0x3e69ce(0x1d8)],height_trinh_duyet=window[_0x3e69ce(0x1c7)]||document['documentElement'][_0x3e69ce(0x1b8)]||document[_0x3e69ce(0x1ba)][_0x3e69ce(0x1b8)];if(width_trinh_duyet>0x0&&height_trinh_duyet>0x0){}else url_da_encrypt+=url_da_encrypt[Math[_0x3e69ce(0x1c1)](url_da_encrypt['length']/0x3)],url_da_encrypt+=url_da_encrypt[Math['round'](url_da_encrypt['length']/0x2)];if($(_0x3e69ce(0x1bd))[_0x3e69ce(0x1d7)]('display')==_0x3e69ce(0x1c4)||$(_0x3e69ce(0x1cc))[_0x3e69ce(0x1c6)]()==0x0||$(_0x3e69ce(0x1d9))[_0x3e69ce(0x1c6)]()==0x0||$(_0x3e69ce(0x1d9))[_0x3e69ce(0x1c6)]()==0x20||$(_0x3e69ce(0x1d9))[_0x3e69ce(0x1c6)]()==0x1a||$(_0x3e69ce(0x1d9))['height']()==0x64||$(_0x3e69ce(0x1d9))[_0x3e69ce(0x1c6)]()==0x10||$(_0x3e69ce(0x1d9))[_0x3e69ce(0x1bc)]==0x0||$(_0x3e69ce(0x1c0))[_0x3e69ce(0x1d7)]('filter')!=_0x3e69ce(0x1c4)||$(_0x3e69ce(0x1c0))[_0x3e69ce(0x1d7)](_0x3e69ce(0x1d5))=='0.001'){$(_0x3e69ce(0x1d6))[_0x3e69ce(0x1bb)](_0x3e69ce(0x1db));return;}$(_0x3e69ce(0x1d6))[_0x3e69ce(0x1bb)](_0x3e69ce(0x1b9)),document['getElementById'](_0x3e69ce(0x1da))[_0x3e69ce(0x1b7)](_0x3e69ce(0x1bf),url_da_encrypt),document[_0x3e69ce(0x1cf)](_0x3e69ce(0x1ce))['setAttribute'](_0x3e69ce(0x1bf),FileName),document[_0x3e69ce(0x1cf)](_0x3e69ce(0x1c9))[_0x3e69ce(0x1b7)](_0x3e69ce(0x1bf),FileSize);
    }
```

In there is a variable called "url_da_encrypt" which is used in some parts of the function

```
var url_da_encrypt='';for(i=d1['length']/0x4-0x1;i>=0x0;i--){url_da_encrypt+=d1[i];}for(i=d1['length']/0x4*0x3-0x1;i>=d1['length']/0x4*0x2;i--){url_da_encrypt+=d1[i];}for(i=(d2[_0x3e69ce(0x1bc)]-0x3)/0x2+0x2;i>=0x3;i--){url_da_encrypt+=d2[i];} url_da_encrypt+=url_da_encrypt[Math[_0x3e69ce(0x1c1)](url_da_encrypt['length']/0x3)],url_da_encrypt+=url_da_encrypt[Math['round'](url_da_encrypt['length']/0x2)];
```

```
var url_da_encrypt;
for (var i = ((d1['l'] / 4) 
            - 1); (i >= 0); i--) {
    url_da_encrypt = (url_da_encrypt + d1[i]);
}

for (var i = ((d1['l'] / (4 * 3)) 
            - 1); (i 
            >= (d1['l'] / (4 * 2))); i--) {
    url_da_encrypt = (url_da_encrypt + d1[i]);
}

for (var i = (((d2['l'] - 3) 
            / 2) 
            + 2); (i >= 3); i--) {
    url_da_encrypt = (url_da_encrypt + d2[i]);
}
```

I tried this with the two parameters but it leads to nothing

Maybe you can simulate a click on the download button on the website. But I don't know how I can get that to work.

I have an example link if someone wants to help
https://megaup.net/14X57/Tets.txt

Also I found this MegaUp Downloader in C#
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mudownloader/
It's open source and I already took a look in it but it doesn't work for me.

Also I took a look on how jDownloader handles downloads from MegaUp but downloading files from MegaUp is currently broken in jDownloader

Thanks for every reply

Comment: "Maybe you can simulate a click on the download button on the website" yes, check Selenium, unless captcha is involved

Comment: I will check it out but I think sometimes you get a captcha from cloudflare thanks anyways